# How to understand such syntax in C

Tags: c, syntax

```
void __not_in_flash_func(adc_capture)(uint16_t *buf, size_t count) {
    //....
}
```

I don't know what this syntax means. Is `__not_in_flas_func` a function or a macro ? How it was crated? Later in code `adc_capture` is calling.

Comment: Lookup what `__not_in_flash_func` is. It might be a macro.

Comment: it is taken from Raspberry pi pico microcontroller example. I can`t find it in docs

Comment: To be fair, a quick Google shows only three very vague hits...

Comment: @maaartin it's probably in one of the header files.

Comment: Judging by those Google hits, it looks like it's either a macro or more of a compiler directive (possibly a compiler directive masquerading as a macro), for the Raspberry Pi compiler, indicating that this function should be placed in SRAM and not in Flash memory.

Answer (score 5):

In [this header file](https://gitlab.melroy.org/micha/pico-sdk/-/blob/master/src/rp2_common/pico_platform/include/pico/platform.h) we can find the following :

```c
#define __not_in_flash(group) __attribute__((section(".time_critical." group)))
#define __not_in_flash_func(x) __not_in_flash(__STRING(x)) x
```

So this macro is used to place a function in a specific section that will be named after the function name, prefixed with *".time_critical."*. In your case the section will be named `.time_critical.adc_capture`.

Note that `__attribute__` is gcc specific. From [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html) about `section` :

> Normally, the compiler places the objects it generates in sections like data and bss. Sometimes, however, you need additional sections, or you need certain particular variables to appear in special sections, for example to map to special hardware. The section attribute specifies that a variable (or function) lives in a particular section.